# Script WiFi Profile Connection pre-logon

Tags: windows-7, domain, wifi, windows-registry

I work for a company that has a lot of remote employees that never come to the office. Currently what happens when these people are hired is I prepare their laptops in the office and then send it to them, Then I ask them to sign into a local admin account and connect to what ever WiFi network they will be working from (Private WiFi network). Then I remote into their computer and use `netsh wlan show profile` to give me the name of said wifi network and go to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` and add a string called `WLAN prelogon` and set the value to `%comspec% /c netsh wlan connect name="<profile name>"` then get them to log out and connect to Cisco anyconnect and log in as themselves.

What I would like to do is have them login to the local admin account, connect to WiFi and then run a script that would find the WiFi profile name and add the registry string automatically cutting down time for me and making this process easier on the user.

Comment: Cisco anyconnect can login **before** the domain logon, I would activate that, as such your user would be able to use their domain login from anywhere.

Comment: I knew that, the problem is i need windows to connect to wifi pre-logon so anyconnect can connect. Windows 7 doesn't automatically do this

Comment: The user can connect offline and connect the wifi, the next time he will be near that hotspot that will work in prelogon.